# Can't add a texture to GL_QUAD

Tags: c++, opengl, mapping, textures

I have a series of rectangles and I am trying to add a texture to just one of them.  Here is my current code:

```
    glEnable (GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    QBitmap image;
    GLuint texture;

    float pixels[] = {
          42, 0, 1,    0, 42, 1,
         -42 , 0, 1,   0, -42, 1,
    };

    image.load("texture.bmp");

    GLuint m_TextureID;

    glGenTextures(1, &m_TextureID);
    glBindTexture ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_TextureID);

    glTexEnvf ( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE , GL_MODULATE);

    glTexParameterf ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameterf ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 84, 84, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, pixels);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_TextureID);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(42, 0, 42);
    glVertex3f(42, 0, -42);
    glVertex3f(-42, 0, -42);
    glVertex3f(-42, 0, 42);
    glEnd();
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where's your call to `glTexImage2D`? The data in the `image` variable isn't going to "magically" jump into the OpenGL texture. Oh, and you should not reload the image/texture upon every redraw.

Comment: In addition you supply GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST as filter, but you never generate mipmaps. This will always result in black.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have altered the code slightly and called glTexImage2D but it still has not changed the texture. I assume it's because I have got the parameters of glTexImage2D wrong?

Comment: @BDL: incomplete mipmap levels will produce white actually, but yes, you'll not see a texture.

Comment: @T.S: Why are you passing `pixels` as parameter to glTexImage2D? `pixels` is some (leftover?) array that not nearly suffices the size of your image. You must pass it the data loaded in image and also use the width and height parameters stored in that variable.